# Authenticationmanager java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

What is the equivalent in java config of this XML authentication-manager config?

`<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"> ... </authentication-manager>`

What i need exactly is convert this xml config to java config :

`<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManagerLdap">
<security:authentication-provider ref="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>

```
<bean id="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" class="ma.gov.adii.beans.AuthenticationAD">
    <constructor-arg value="adii.gov.ma"/>
    <constructor-arg value="ldap://addouane.adii.gov.ma:389/"/>
    <property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true" />
    <property name="userDetailsContextMapper" ref="manageLoginService" /> 
</bean>`
```

My login clas is like this :
`public class LoginMBean implements Serializable {  @Autowired private AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerLdap;`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

THE ANSWER IS LIKE THIS :

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {

return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}

@Autowired
void registerProvider(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authLdap) {
    authLdap.authenticationProvider(ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider());
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).